# PHP - get serial number of hard disk ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I use `shell_exec('wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber 2>&1');` to get serial number of disk drive on window and it's working well.

Now i'm test that on ubuntu and i use `echo shell_exec("hdparm -I /dev/sda");` it's empty, nothing shown. How to get serial number in `linux` thanks

Edit

i fogot `2>&1` but it say `/dev/sda: Permission denied` ?

Comment: What do you want to happen if a system has no local disks (you can run Unix entirely off network drives, for example)? Or if it has multiple disks? (Also: I just tried this on my Ubuntu install and the reason it fails for me is that I don't have `hdparm` installed at all...) Do you have control over the server environment? Can you specify that the end-user has to have `hdparm` installed to run your PHP script?

Comment: Leaves to say that hdparm also requires root permissions.

Comment: The real question here might be: why? This is quite an unusual requirement for a PHP script. If we know why you feel you want to get the serial number of a hard drive, it's possible we could suggest an alternate, more "normal" way of achieving what you want.

Comment: @MattGibson why it is "uncommon" for a PHP script to do that? this part I don't get

Comment: @hek2mgl PHP scripts don't normally need detailed information about the hardware of the boxes they're running on. If you're using `shell_exec`, you've pretty much left PHP and entered the realm of wanting to do things that are outside its norms. Sometimes that's quite reasonable, but you rarely see a language designed to serve web pages needing to know the serial number of some random disk in the box it happens to be running on. There's... a marked difference between the abstraction level of the language and the information being requested, I'd say.

Comment: @MattGibson I need to manager or store `serialnumber` of disk using `php` and `mysql`

Comment: yes, it's a very unusual requirement. Why does your script care what server it's running on? If the disk fails and you reinstall the app on a different hard disk, will it explode because the numbers no longer match?

Comment: @sevenseacat but i get `Permission denied`?

Comment: see other comments and other comments on the answers for the other question.

Comment: @sevenseacat i saw all of them, but it don't fix that

Comment: @MattGibson From the php man page: `PHP is a widely-used general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited for Web development and can be embedded into HTML.` I personally had often to do with tasks that where related to system programming, in PHP.